# I have tried everything but still not able to redirect the Guest user into VF along with query parameters

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Hi community I really need your help please. I have got stuck in this problem for days now and I have searched so many things regarding this, that how can I solve this but I couldn't do it.
What I am doing I am trying to redirect from LWC component to VF page along with query parameters for guest user. When I am redirecting to only VF page for guest user then it works perfectly fine but when I add a query parameters then it asks for a login. Don't know what I am missing. The same is working fine for the community log in user but creating glitch in guest user.
Here is the code.

HTML

```
<div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <div class="slds-p-around_none slds-m-top_x-small slds-m-bottom_medium slds-m-horizontal_none">
                        <div class="custom-box slds-p-around_medium slds-text-align_center">
                            <div slot="footer" class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                <lightning-button variant="brand" label={payNowText} icon-name="utility:moneybag" class="slds-m-left_x-small" onclick={navigateToVFPage}>
                                </lightning-button>
                                <template if:true = {showPopUp}>
                                    <iframe id="vfFrame" src={vfURL} class="wk-iframe" height="500px" width="770px"></iframe>
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JS file

```
vfURL = "https://sandbox-fun-java-6633-dev-ed-176cc1dd4e4.cs90.force.com";
navigateToVFPage() {
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: '/wedgy/checkoutPayment?orderId=' + this.order_id
        }
    }).then(vfURL => {
    window.open(vfURL);
    });
}
```

When I am removing this part "?orderId=' + this.order_id" then it is redirecting me to the VF page for the guest user as well but whenever I am binding this then it is asking for login

Comment: You're query parameter shouldn't cause you to redirect to a login page. The only thing I can think of is dat that your guest user doesn't have acces to the order object and then gets redirected to an error page with a login screen. But that's a wild guess.

Comment: Well you have a very good guess it might be the issue but the issue was having the Contact part. I have commented the contact part in apex and it ran.
But as you said that guest user does not have order object access it is also correct